# How to sort inside of Excel Spreadsheet programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I have this code currently in my c# program but i was trying to translate it into vb.net, But I'm having a problem on this part of the code.

```
C# Code 
dynamic allDataRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
allDataRange.Sort(allDataRange.Columns[2], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending);
```

And translate it to

```
VB.NET Code
Dim allDataRange As Dynamic = Worksheet.UsedRange
allDataRange.Sort(allDataRange.Columns(2), Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending)
```

The error saying is Type is Expected in Dynamic 
And the suggestion is to Generate a new class and new type 
And I did not understand this part why should I generate a class?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Dim allDataRange As Dynamic
```

to:

```
Dim allDataRange As Excel.Range
```

or just (if you use `Option Infer On`):

```
Dim allDataRange
```

Answer (score 0):

sorting the whole sheet by the key you prefer (this example is for sorting A-C in descending order by column A - recorded macro)

```
 Columns("A:C").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & lastRow), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question.